# How can I select only one unique date_time record from the Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

```
SELECT date_time,
       case when COUNT(*) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end CNT
FROM table
WHERE bid='BD11' AND
      date_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND
                        TO_DATE ('2016/08/11', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY date_time
```

...Here is my Query
date_time    count

```
2015-08-01 1
2015-08-01  1
2015-08-01  1
2015-08-01  1
2015-08-01  1
2015-08-01  1
2015-08-02   1
2015-08-02  1
2015-08-02   1
2015-08-03  1
2015-08-03 1
2015-08-03  1
```

it shoud print come like
2015-08-01  1
2015-08-02   1
2015-08-03  1

Answer (score 1):

Add 'distinct' keyword to date_time in the Select part of the query

Comment: i have tried in same ..its printing same as like previos

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct or unique.

```
SELECT trunc(date_time)
       ,count(*)
FROM table
WHERE bid='BD11' AND
      date_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND
                        TO_DATE ('2016/08/11', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
group by trunc(date_time)
```

Comment: i want with the count as well

Comment: Edited for that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please see some flaws in your queries.

Firstly if you want single records for each date add distinct or group by on unique keys.
Secondly your `case` will always evalute to `1`. So why are you writing it . It doesnot make any sense to me.

```
SELECT trunc(date_time),
           case when COUNT(*) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end CNT
    FROM table
    WHERE bid='BD11' AND
          date_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND
                            TO_DATE ('2016/08/11', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   GROUP BY trunc(date_time);
```

See demo:

```
 with t_moored_buoy_rtqc (date_time, COUNT) AS ( /*****This is yoour table data***/
                                                select TO_DATE ('2015/08/01 10:13:13', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'),'1'  from dual                              
                                                union all 
                                                select TO_DATE ('2015/08/01 10:13:15', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'),'1' from dual 
                                                union all 
                                                select TO_DATE ('2015/09/01 10:13:13', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'),'1' from dual  ) 
select  trunc(date_time), case when COUNT(*) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end CNT 
from t_moored_buoy_rtqc 
group by trunc(date_time)
```

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function its coming liek this when i am running

Comment: Not sure how are you running ti..Its working fine. See demo

Comment: The query is woking..See udpated post and try again

Comment: What are you trying to do man. Run the first query. The query you just pasted above is not correct. I created a dataset to make you understand the the query is runing fine. See first query. its working.

Comment: You date_time is having timestamp as well, so see the updated one . Use it and you will get the result

Comment: i changed king but coming same output :( please help me out xing

Comment: God only knows why its not working for you coz you can see demo that its working..

Answer (score 0):

Both group by and distinct version should work correctly if your date_time column does not actually contain time. Can you confirm that you store only dates in the DB, and that client you are using is not masking the time part?

[Edit] Since you also want to have that count:

```
select trunc(date_time) date_time,
       case when count(*) > 1 then 1 else 0 end cnt
  from table
 where bid = 'BD11'
   and date_time between to_date('2015/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
                         to_date('2016/08/11', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
 group by trunc(date_time);
```

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with that count - it will always return 1. Notice that I changed ">=" to ">" - thus above query will return 1 if there is more than one repetition of the date, and 0 if there is exactly one row with the date.

This query will return both date and time:

```
select to_char(date_time, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss am') date_time
  from table
 where bid = 'BD11'
   and date_time between to_date('2015/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
                         to_date('2015/08/11', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Also, do you want data for 2016/08/11? The way you wrote it you will not get data for that day, unless it is exactly midnight. If you need everything on that day then use ">=" and "<":

```
   and date_time >= to_date('2015/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   and date_time < to_date('2015/08/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: Thank u its Working